# Ruby 1.9 prints strings twice

Tags: ruby

```
class Test
def printsomething
p "lol"
end
end
teet = Test.new
p "#{teet.printsomething}"
```

Output for above code is "lol"\n"lol"

why is this happening? I am running ruby 1.9.2 Archlinux x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is an inspect not really meant to be used to output text string. What it does is prints out the literal content of an object not an escaped string.

Just replace `p` with `puts`

You can see what I mean if you do this:

```
p "#{teet}"
=> "#<Test:0x00000100850678>"
```

Notice how it's inside quotes.

Comment: thanx for the answer, I am new with ruby, very confused with @variables, self and throw catch vs rescue keywords.

Comment: How does it answer OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that Ruby does when it sees a double-quoted string is replacing the `#{expr}` parts with the result of evaluated `expr`. For example, `"#{2+2}"` becomes `"4"`. So, let's see what happens here. Ruby evaluates `teet.printsomething`. During this evaluation it executes the method and it prints "lol" in the 3-rd line. Note that although the method `printsomething` doesn't have a `return` statement, it nevertheless returns some value: it's the value returned by the last statement of that method. The return value of `p object` is the `object` itself, so the result of the method `printsomething` is `"lol"`. This result now replaces the `#{}` part in the string, and the string becomes `"lol"` instead of `"#{teet.printsomething}"`. Now the `p` method in the 7-th line is executed and outputs "lol" again.

What happens if you replace `p` with `puts`? The difference is that the return value of `puts` is `nil`. When the result of `expr` is `nil`, the whole expression `#{}` is replaced by empty string. So the 7-th line becomes `puts ""`. As a result, the whole program outputs "lol" followed by an empty line.

Comment: The question heading mentions ruby 1.9, and there is a difference between version here. In ruby 1.8, the `p` method returns `nil`, which results in an empty quoted string being printed after `"lol"`.